Exhaustion by compact sets $\implies$ exhaustion-function?
Let $X$ be a topological space. An exhaustion by compact sets in $X$ is a family $(K_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of compact subsets of $X$ such that $X=\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty K_n$ and $K_0^\rm{o}\subseteq K_0\subseteq K_1^\rm{o}\subseteq K_1\subseteq\cdots$. An exhaustion-function on $X$ is a continuous function $f:X\to(0,\infty)$ such that $f^{-1}((0,c])$ is compact for all $c\in(0,\infty)$ (If I replace $f^{-1}((0,c])$ by $\overline{f^{-1}((0,c))}$, then I get a weaker definition; I do not know which definition is better).
It is true that if an exhaustion-function on $X$ exists, then an exhaustion by compact sets in $X$ exists. The converse holds if $X$ is Hausdorff.
Is the converse true in general? That is, if $X$ admits an exhaustion by compact sets in $X$, then does $X$ admit an exhaustion-function on $X$?

Where did you see this definition of exhaustion function?  It would seem more natural to define it as a function $f:X\to[0,\infty)$ with the appropriate property.

@PatrickR I saw it in an exam, but it did not say that it is an exhaustion-function. I think your definition is equivalent to mine because you can add $1$ to $f:X\to[0,\infty)$.

There exists a strongly connected, non-compact, exhaustible by compact sets space $X$ such as particular point topology on a countably infinite set.
Then any continuous function $f:X\to (0, \infty)$ is constant, so that $f^{-1}((0, c]) = X$ for any large enough $c$, and so there's no exhaustion function.

Edit: As per request, here's an example that's $T_1$.
Let $X = [-1, 1]\setminus \{0\}\cup \{0_n : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ be the interval $[-1, 1]$ with countably many origins. The topology on $X$ is that from a quotient map $q:Y = \bigsqcup_{n=1}^\infty\left( [-1, 1]\times \{n\}\right) \to X$ where $q(t, n) = t$ for all $t\in [-1, 1]\setminus\{0\}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and $q(0, n) = 0_n$.

$X$ is $T_1$, since $q^{-1}(\{t\}) = \{(t, n) : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and $q^{-1}(\{0_n\}) = \{(0, n)\}$ are closed.

$X$ is pseudocompact, since if $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then so is $g = f\circ q$, and since the functions $t\mapsto g(t, n)$ are equal except possibly at $t = 0$, from continuity we see that they must be equal at $0$ as well i.e. there is a function $h:[-1, 1]\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(t, n) = h(t)$ for all $t\in [-1, 1], n\in\mathbb{N}$. Since $[-1, 1]$ is compact, $h$ is bounded, and so $g$ is as well.

$X$ is not compact, since $U_n = [-1, 0)\cup (0, 1]\cup \{0_n\}$ are open because $q^{-1}(U_n)$ is open in $Y$. The cover of $X$ by $U_n$ is easily seen to have no finite subcover, since $U_n$ is the only member that contains $0_n$.

$X$ is exhaustible by compact sets, since the sets $K_n = U_1\cup ...\cup U_n$ are compact (images of compact sets $\bigcup_{k=1}^n \left( [-1, 1]\times\{k\}\right)$) and open (see 3). Moreover $X = \bigcup_n K_n$. So $(K_n)_n$ is an exhaustion by open sets of $X$.


From (1) this example is $T_1$. From (4) its exhaustible by compact sets. From (2) and (3), there is no exhaustion function $f:X\to (0, \infty)$, since for large enough $c$ we see that $f^{-1}((0, c]) = X$ is not compact.

For completion, here's a proof of the fact claimed by the OP that I apparently can't include into the body of their question:
Proposition. If $X$ is Hausdorff and exhaustible by compact sets, then exhaustion-function exists.
Proof: Since $X$ is exhaustible by compact sets, $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff, hence $T_{3.5}$ (e.g. $X$ has a compactification so its a subspace of $T_4$ space). Fix an exhaustion by compact sets $(K_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of $X$. For each $n$, since $K_n$ and $(K_{n+1}^\circ)^c$ are disjoint closed sets, one of which is compact, there exists a continuous function $f_n:X\to [n, n+1]$ such that $f_n[K_n] \subseteq \{n\}$ and $f_n[(K_{n+1}^\circ)^c] \subseteq \{n+1\}$. Define $f:X\to [0, \infty)$ by $f(x) = f_n(x)$ for $x\in K_{n+1}\setminus K_n$ and $f[K_0]\subseteq \{0\}$. Then $f(x) = f_n(x)$ for $x\in K_{n+1}\setminus K_n^\circ$ so that $f$ restricted to $K_{n+1}\setminus K_n^\circ$ and to $K_0$ is continuous. If $x\in X$ then $x\in K_{n+2}^\circ\setminus K_n$ or $x\in K_1^\circ$, and this open set intersects at most two of the form $K_{n+1}\setminus K_n^\circ$ or $K_0$. So $f$ is continuous on a locally finite family of closed sets, hence on their union $X$. By replacing $f$ by $x\mapsto f(x)+1$ one obtains an exhaustion function. $\square$
